# Flex: trying to generate a C++ lexer using Flex; "unrecognized rule" error

Tags: c++, flex-lexer, lex, lexer

I am trying to generate a lexer using `flex`. This is my definition file `lexer.l`:

```
%{
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//#define YY_DECL extern "C" int yylex()
%}

staffType "grand" | "treble" | "bass" | "alto" | "tenor"
upperRomans "I" | "II" | "III" | "IV" | "V" | "VI" | "VII"
lowerRomans "i" | "ii" | "iii" | "iv" | "v" | "vi" | "vii"
quality "dim" | "halfdim" | "aug" | "maj" | "min"

%%

[ \t\n]+ { ; // Ignore arbitrary whitespace. }
{staffType} { cout << "Staff" << endl; }
{upperRomans} { cout << "Upper roman" << endl; }
{lowerRomans} { cout << "Lower roman" << endl; }
"doublebar" { cout << "End of line" << endl; }
. { cout << "Parse error" << endl; }

%%

int main(int, char**) {
    // lex through the input
    yylex();
}
```

However, after invoking:

```
flex lexer.l
```

I get:

```
lexer.l:18: unrecognized rule
lexer.l:19: unrecognized rule
lexer.l:20: unrecognized rule
```

My flex version is `flex 2.5.35 Apple(flex-31)`.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Which are lines 18, 19, 20? NB I wouldn't reduce the staff types etc. here: I would put that into the grammar, and just recognize keywords in here. And note that `yylex()` will only scan one token. You need to loop until it returns 0 or -1 or whatever it does at end of stream.

Comment: @EJP thanks. {upperRomans}... is line 18, as I have included the entire source.

Comment: Is it possible that the C++ comment in the whitespace rule disables the closing flex brace? Try removing the comment or replacing it with a `/* */`-style one.

Comment: @Angew Unfortunately, removing it has no effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is about the whitespaces between the different tokens in your pattern. It must be:

```
[...]
staffType "grand"|"treble"|"bass"|"alto"|"tenor"
upperRomans "I"|"II"|"III"|"IV"|"V"|"VI"|"VII"
lowerRomans "i"|"ii"|"iii"|"iv"|"v"|"vi"|"vii"
quality "dim"|"halfdim"|"aug"|"maj"|"min"
[...]
```

It's written in the [manpage of flex](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/flex/manpage.html).

> PATTERNS
>         The patterns in the input are written  using  an extended
>         set of regular expressions. These are:
>   
>        [...]
>        r|s        either an r or an s